# How to make a python list indexable alphabetically?

Tags: python, list, indexing

Here's what I mean.

Given a list

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to override the list's **getitem** so that `l['a']` returns the same as `l['A']` which would return `l[0]`.

This sounds like a weird idea but here's why this would be very useful for me. I am making a chess game and the board is stored as a 2D list. As per chess convention, the ranks are integers **[1-8]** and the files are letters **[a-h]**. The rank index is already an integer, I just have to subtract one from it. However, for the files, it would be nice to support indexing.

How can I accomplish this? For completeness sake here's part of the board class:

```
class Board(Tools):

    default_order = [Rook, Knight, Bishop, Queen, King, Bishop, Knight, Rook]

    blank_board = [[Blank() for __ in range(8)] for _ in range(8)]

    def __init__(self, player1, player2):
        self.board = self.blank_board
        self.board[1] = [piece(player2) for piece in self.default_order]
        self.board[0] = [Pawn(player2) for _ in range(8)]
        self.board[6] = [Pawn(player1) for _ in range(8)]
        self.board[7] = [piece(player1) for piece in self.default_order]
        player2.alive = self.board[0] + self.board[1]
        player1.alive = self.board[7] + self.board[6]

    # The following two magic methods allow us to do Board[i][j] instead of Board.board[i][j]
    # This is a shortcut but should be used because it prevents us from deleting a piece.
    # A piece should be replaced by a Blank instead.
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.board[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.board[index] = value
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by `l['a']` list indices needs to be integer

Comment: And why can't you use a data structure like this - `l = {}; l['a'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]; l['b'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` and so on. By doing this you will be able to reference like l['a'][1] or l['b'][5] so on and so forth

Comment: Exactly. How can I make it so that the index 'a' gets mapped to 0?

Comment: I think you're on the right track by overriding `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`. Is your actual difficulty in how to map letters to numbers?

Comment: Use something like `l={'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2}`

Comment: `ord('a')-97 == 0`, by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I implemented my solution:

```
# The following two magic methods allow us to do Board[i][j] instead of Board.board[i][j]
# This is a shortcut but should be used because it prevents us from deleting a piece.
# A piece should be replaced by a Blank instead.
def __getitem__(self, index):
    if type(index) is int:
        return self.board[index]
    # else assume it is a str with the file then rank like 'e3'
    f, r = index
    x = [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0][int(r)-1]
    y = ord(f) - ord('a')
    return self.board[x][y]
```

This allows me to do both board[x][y] and board['fr'] where fr are the file and rank. Thanks to all the other users that posted answers, it helped me formulate this one.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me what you need is a dict and not a list. A dict like this may solve your issue

```
l = {}
l['a'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
l['b'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

That way you can access elements like `l['a'][1]` or `l['b'][6]` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
d = {}
for i, v in enumerate(l):
    d[chr(i + 65)] = v  # Use 'A', ... as key.
    d[chr(i + 97)] = v  # Use 'a', ... as key.
```

Then you can access the values of `l` (or copies thereof) using `d['A']` and `d['a']`.

Note that if you have more than 158 values in your list then the assignment will fail because `chr` takes only integers `0 <= x < 256` as an argument.

Alternatively, if you want to stay up-to-date with the original list `l`, you can use a wrapper class:

```
class AlphStore:
    def __init__(self, original_list):
        self._l = original_list

    def __getitem__(self, v):
        return self._l[ord(v.upper()) - 65]
```

You can use it like that:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> store = AlphStore(l)
>>> store['A']
1
>>> store['a'] is store['A']
True
```

Comment: This will be hard to maintain as I need to update the copy every time. Interesting solution though!

Comment: I added an example for how to stay up-to-date with the original list :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your list with a class like the below which implements custom use of square brackets,

```
class AlphabeticalList(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    offset = ord("a")

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[ord(key) - self.offset]

    def __setitem(self, key, value):
        self.data[ord(key) - self.offset] = value


test_list = AlphabeticalList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

print(test_list["a"])
```

This might be helpful if there is further custom logic you need to implement for your container.

Alternatively you could use a `ordereddict` from the `collections` module which gives you ordered elements like a list but allows you to index by string.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

In your `__getitem__` do this

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    import string
    index = string.ascii_lowercase.find(key.lower())
    return whatever_your_list_is_named[index]
```

edit: forgot to actually return the thing.....

Comment: Doesn't getitem need to return the item?